# How to prevent OCX unregister after un installation of a application (VB.net converted from vb6)

Tags: vb.net, installation, setup-project, ocx

We have a vb6 project, which we converted to vb.net.
We have recently moved to Windows server 2016 and using VS 2019.
We have created setup project which installs the application.
After uninstallation, some of the Shared OCX files like mscomct2.ocx, mshflxgd.ocx and msdatgrd.ocx were unregistering and other applications giving an error like its not registered.
After manual registration like regsvr32.exe mscomct2.ocx its working.

**Help is needed to stop unregistering OCX files after uninstallation of setup project.
I have tried with VS 2019 extension and also Installsheild, both results same**

Comment: Enable the `Permanent` property of the shared files. See [How to configure Setup to handle OCX's](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/596db166-4e85-4931-b305-be43b9545ed1/how-to-configure-setup-to-handle-ocxs?forum=vbgeneral).

Comment: I have selected OCX file Register property to "vsdrfDoNotRegister", after that it was working fine, thank you.